# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Content template for column type "custom_text" was not found")

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm writing a custom plugin for Prestashop 1.7 for adding a new column in OrderList and I can't solve this issue.

In the local environment, it works but not on the production site.

Version Prestashop : 1.7.7.4
Php : 7.3.28

The difference between dev and production is the OS. Windows on dev machine and Debian on production.

I have tested my code with Prestashop 1.7.7.3 and 1.7.7.4.

My hook :

```
Path: /modules/mymodule/mymodule.php

/**
 * @param array $params
 */
public function hookActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
{
    /** @var GridDefinitionInterface $definition */
    $definition = $params['definition'];

    $definition
        ->getColumns()
        ->addAfter(
            'country_name',
            (new HtmlTypeColumn('ldDeliveryDate'))
                ->setName($this->l('Date de livraison'))
                ->setOptions([
                    'ModuleClass' => new MyModule(),
                    'ldDeliveryDate' => "Aujourd'hui"
                ])
        )
    ;
}
```

My class :

```
Path : /modules/mymodule/src/Grid/Columns/HtmlTypeColumn.php


final class HtmlTypeColumn extends AbstractColumn {
    public function getType() {
        return 'custom_text';
    }
    protected function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) 
        $resolver
            ->setRequired([
                'ModuleClass',
                'ldDeliveryDate'
            ])
            ->setAllowedTypes('ModuleClass', 'object')
            ->setAllowedTypes('ldDeliveryDate', 'string');
    }
}
```

And the error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Content template for column type "custom_text" was not found").
```

Does someone have an idea?
Thank you :)

Comment: To test I placed my "custom_text.html.twig" file in the folder: "/ src / PrestaShopBundle / Resources / views / Admin / Common / Grid / Columns / Content" of prestashop.

And everything works.

I am still looking for a permanent solution. If you have a solution, I'm interested.

Comment: I have open a github issue if someone need more information in the future. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/25055

Comment: Hi @charly, can you please check https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/25576